# sql 2014 group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a sql query which returns me this result.

```
StudCount   GPA Cale_      Year
 1         2.0 - 2.49      2010
 1         2.5 - 2.99      2014
 1         3.0 - 3.49      2003
 1         3.0 - 3.49      2010
 1         3.0 - 3.49      2013
 1         3.5 - 3.99      2006
 2         4.5 - 5.00      2010
```

Now I want one more column which should display the number of students year wise. that means for 2010 4 students should come. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 drop table if exists dbo.Students;

 create table dbo.Students (
StudCount int
, GPACale_ varchar(100)
, Year int
);


insert into dbo.Students (StudCount, GPACale_, Year)
values (1, '2.0 - 2.49', 2010)
, (1, '2.5 - 2.99', 2014)
, (1, '3.0 - 3.49', 2003)
, (1, '3.0 - 3.49', 2010)
, (1, '3.0 - 3.49', 2013)
, (1, '3.5 - 3.99', 2006)
, (2, '4.5 - 5.00', 2010)


select
*
, sum(s.StudCount) over (partition by s.Year order by s.Year) as Sum
from dbo.Students s
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SUM` Aggregate function with a `GROUP BY` on the `Year` column

```
SELECT Year, SUM(StudCount)
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY Year
```

Comment: Above result I am getting by joining multiple columns. not from one table

Comment: There isn't enough info in your original question for anything other than a generic answer. Both presented answers will work, but without knowing your actual query to understand which columns/tables are in play, we can't provide a query that will exactly match what you want to achieve. Posting the actual query that generates the results is always a good idea!

Comment: @Dave, we can just wrap his query without seeing it, no? `SELECT * FROM (/*hisqueryhere*/) AS T`. Granted, providing could help and in some cases (*not this though*) is necessary.

Comment: I agree it was just a comment based on the answer Hybris95 gave which is accurate and would work when added CORRECTLY to a query, but from the OP's comment it potentially shows a (no offence intended) lower SQL knowledge in how to translate that answer into his overall query. He may need some help working in a SUM(alias.studcount) value where needed. Just trying to help (but sometimes come across as a dick in text because, the internet)